# Insert the „Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210204)” called CD to the /cdrom/ drive and press enter

Tags: 20.04

So I have ran into some trouble installing g++. When I try to use the "sudo apt install g++", command it asks me if I really want to install it, and when I say yes, it just leaves me this message: "Insert the „Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS *Focal Fossa* - Release amd64 (20210204)” called CD to the /cdrom/ drive and press enter" (Or something like that, I tried to translate it from Hungarian)

I give you an image of my problem, however my Ubuntu is in Hungarian, so i don't think that it would be useful. Here it is: [My terminal, under Ubuntu 20.04.02.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zt8s.png)

I have already tried to get the .iso file and just mount it to my cd drive, but it didn't solve the problem.

Should I just reinstall Ubuntu or what should I do?

Comment: If you need help with the translations from the pictures, just let us know.

Comment: Best to include text in the quest not as a screen shot. In this case any one reading your question could also  use translation to read in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks like you must have put your sources (where Ubuntu gets the packages) to only the install CD.

Fix this by opening the **Software and Updates** app, and ticking everything (you want to install) listed under **Downloadable from the Internet**.

Comment: g++ is in 'main', so only one of those five boxes need be checked.